# wso2 retail bank example app - add server inside Eclipse?

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I'm trying to follow the wso2 retail banking sample, as outlined at http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS310/Retail+Banking+Sample

I've got to the stage 'Deploy the Carbon Application Project into the WSO2 App Server' and I don't understand how to create a server.

When I follow the instructions then in Eclipse I get a 'New Server' form appear.   If  I enter the WSO2 App Server folder address into 'Carbon home' text box then a warning error appears at the top of the form:

```
      Missing classpath entry C:\jlibs\wso2\wso2as-5.2.0\lib\api
```

Am I supposed to setup class path entries for each of the WSO2 server products? The 'next' and 'Finish' buttons are disabled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When I follow the sample I was able to successfully add a new carbon server. What is the developer studio version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You encounter this error when you select the incorrect Carbon Server family from the list of Servers in the Dev Studio servers view. If you are running App Server 5.2.0, you need to select either WSO2 Carbon 4.2 based Server (only available in Dev Studio 3.5.0) or WSO2 Carbon 4.0 based Server in older Dev Studio versions.

Please follow the instructions in [1](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS320/Deploying+and+Debugging#DeployingandDebugging-DeployingaC-ApptoarunningserverinsideEclipse) on how to add a Carbon Server to Developer Studio.

Also please find the webinar conducted on the same scenario from [2](http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2012/05/enterprise-use-case-application-development-using-wso2-developer-studio/). It will help you to solve all the other issues you encounter.

[1](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS320/Deploying+and+Debugging#DeployingandDebugging-DeployingaC-ApptoarunningserverinsideEclipse). http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS320/Deploying+and+Debugging#DeployingandDebugging-DeployingaC-ApptoarunningserverinsideEclipse

[2](http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2012/05/enterprise-use-case-application-development-using-wso2-developer-studio/). http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2012/05/enterprise-use-case-application-development-using-wso2-developer-studio/

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana